# Excel - How can we replace multiple characters or whole words in a cell using LAMBDA()

Tags: excel, lambda, excel-formula, office365, excel-lambda

At risk of being off-topic I decided to do a little Q&A as I'm pretty excited about a new function MS is introducing to Excel365; the `LAMBDA()` function. If the general opinion is such that this is off-topic, please let me know and I can take down the Q&A.

The `LAMBDA()` function is basically your way in Excel itself to create your **own** function. You then can go ahead and call this function throughout your entire workbook. But the absolute great thing (IMHO) about it is that it is able to call itself within the function, thus being *recursive*!

We all know the tedious nested `SUBSTITUTE()` functions if one has to swap multiple characters, or clear a string from certain characters and even whole words. So the question is: How do we avoid that and use `LAMBDA()` to our advantage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***EDIT 22-3-2022***:

As per the new functionality, one can choose to opt for:

```
=CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"+","#","%","*","(",")","!"}))
```

I'll keep the original answer using `LAMBDA()` intact below:

---

***Original Answer***:

So let's create an example of a string that needs cleaning; `a+b#c%d*e(f)g!h`.

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SUBALL(A1,"+#%*()!","")
```

Where `SUBALL()` is the name of our `LAMBDA()` function I created through the "name manager" menu and reads as follows:

```
=LAMBDA(str,chrs,sub,IF(chrs="",str,SUBALL(SUBSTITUTE(str,LEFT(chrs),sub),RIGHT(chrs,LEN(chrs)-1),"")))
```

Core of this formula are the 3 variables:

- `str` - A reference to the string to be cleaned.
- `chrs` - A string of characters to be substituted.
- `sub` - What do we want our characters to be replaced with?

The 4th parameter is a nested `IF()`. Because of the recursive calls we need a way out of an otherwise infinite loop. Therefor we test if `chrs=""`. If `TRUE` we return the final string with all substituted characters. If `FALSE` we call the function *again*. The great thing here is we can alter all variables! This is important because we can thus `SUBSTITUTE()` the leftmost character *and* we can cut that same character of the string of replacements.

We could also take it up a notch and replace element from an array. For example:

[image]

The formula in `B1`:

```
=SUBALL(A1,{"STR1","STR2","STR3"},"-")
```

Note, you can also hardcode a single value or reference a single cell (or any vertical range for that matter). Obviously this will impact the way we handle recursion. There may be a prettier way, but I came up with:

```
=LAMBDA(str,del,sub,IF(COUNTA(del)=1,SUBSTITUTE(str,@del,sub),SUBALL(SUBSTITUTE(str,@del,sub),INDEX(del,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(del)-1,,2)),sub)))
```

The core of the function is still the same, but as mentioned we have now used an array. So our `IF()` will no longer check for empty value, but if there is only a single element in our array. If so, it will go do a single `SUBSTITUTE()`, but if not, then it will recursively call `SUBALL()` untill we have sliced enough values from our array through `INDEX()` so all values are substituted.

There you have it, a recursive function that you can now call throughout your entire workbook. Pretty cool.

Comment: Very useful but the only problem is going to be when you write for someone else and they aren't using Office365

Comment: @TobyPython, that's a problem with all version-based functions unfortunately.

Comment: what's the meaning of `@del` - why the @ symbol?

Comment: Also I posted a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/253549/146810) on recursive Lambdas on code review, maybe post yours there if you are looking for another way of doing it - for example taking a range and using `Offset` to iterate over it may be a cleaner approach, I'm not sure

Comment: @Greedo, the thing is I knew about `OFFSET()` but since that is volatile I don't know if it would make the `LAMBDA()` volatile too. The `@` makes that we do not use an entire array but make sure we take the first element from our del array (or string). Without it, the `LAMBDA()` messes up. Hope that helps. Thanks for your interest in the function =)

Answer (score 1):

Well, best answer has already been declared, apparently, but, for what its worth, this doesn't handle consecutive delimitters of the same type very well,

Say, for instance, say I have "¬¬" and I wish to replace only such instances with a single "¬"; then applying the SubAll function will in fact remove every occurrence of "¬" - not just when these occur in adjacent 'pairs':

(The converse - adding an extra "¬", simply add an extra one).

Far more efficient/savvy (in my biased opinion), reduce - requires Office 365. btw.

a,

[image: Reduce - more efficient habibi]

```
=REDUCE(B2,SEQUENCE(5),LAMBDA(a_,b_,SUBSTITUTE(a_,"¬¬","¬")))
```