# Replace by regular expresion in Excel

Tags: excel, regex, excel-formula, powerquery, regexp-replace

I have a list in Excel like the following:

```
1 / 6 / 45
123
1546
123 456 
1247 /% 456 /
```

I want to create a new column with all sequences of consecutive non digits replaced by a character. In Google Sheets, this is easy using `=REGEXREPLACE(A1&"/","\D+",",")`, resulting in:

```
1,6,45,
123,
1546,
123,456 
1247,456,
```

In that formula `A1&"/"` is needed in order for `REGEXREPLACE` to work with numbers. No big deal, just adds a comma at the end.

How can we do this in Excel? Pure Power Query (not R, not Python, just M) is very much encouraged. **VBA and other clickable Excel features are unacceptable (like find and replace)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Excel 365:

[image]

In `B1`:

```
=LET(X,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(--X),X," ")))," ",","))
```

Or if streaks of digits are always delimited by at least a space:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]"))
```

Another option, if you have got access to it, is `LAMBDA()`. Make a function to replace all kind of characters, something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65364905/9758194). Without `LAMBDA()` and `TEXTJOIN()` I think your best bet would be to start nesting `SUBSTITUTE()` functions.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. This should have 20000 upvotes! Why it is so difficult to do the most basic things in Excel, the world may never know -_-

Comment: @Ruslan, glad this old post has helped you out!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Power Query solution.
It makes use of the `List.Accumulate` function to determine whether to add a digit, or a comma, to the string:

Note that the code replicates what you show for results.  If you prefer to avoid trailing (and/or leading) commas, it can be easily modified.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "textToList", each List.Combine({Text.ToList([Column1]),{","}})),
    
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "commaTerminators", each List.Accumulate(
      [textToList],"", (state,current) => 
            if List.Contains({"0".."9"},current)
                then state & current
            else if Text.EndsWith(state,",") 
                then state  
            else state & ",")),
        
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"textToList"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

***Edit** To eliminate leading/trailing commas, we add the `Text.Trim` function which, in Power Query, allows defining a specific text to Trim from the start/end:*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "textToList", each List.Combine({Text.ToList([Column1]),{","}})),
    
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "commaTerminators", each 
    Text.Trim(
        List.Accumulate(
            [textToList],"", (state,current) => 
                if List.Contains({"0".."9"},current)
                    then state & current
                else if Text.EndsWith(state,",") 
                    then state  
                else state & ","),
        ",")),
        
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"textToList"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

***VBA UDF** You mentioned you did not want VBA, but not clear if you were restricting that to a "clickable".  Here is a user defined function that you can use on a worksheet directly. It uses the VBA regex engine which allows easy extraction of multiple matches*

*You can enter a formula on the worksheet such as `=commaSep(cell_ref)` to get the same results as shown above in my second PQ example*

```
Option Explicit
Function commaSep(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Dim sTemp As String
    
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\d+"
    If .test(S) Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        sTemp = ""
        For Each M In MC
            sTemp = sTemp & "," & M
        Next M
        commaSep = Mid(sTemp, 2)
    Else
        commaSep = "no digits"
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another variation if you have `TEXTJOIN` function available.

`=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFERROR(MID(A2,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2))),1)+0," ")))," ",",")`

Answer (score 1):

And another option in Power Query.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTQVzADYhNTpVgdINfIGEKbmpjBBIByZgpQjom5gr4qWEBfKTYWAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    x1 = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "x1", each Text.ToList([Column1])),
    x2 = Table.AddColumn(x1, "x2", each List.Transform([x1], each if Text.Contains("0123456789", _) then _ else " "  )),
    x3 = Table.AddColumn(x2, "x3", each Text.Split(Text.Combine([x2])," ")),
    x4 = Table.AddColumn(x3, "x4", each List.Transform([x3], each if Text.Contains("0123456789", try Text.At(_,0) otherwise " ") then _&"," else "" )),
    x5 = Table.AddColumn(x4, "x5", each Text.Combine([x4])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(x5,{"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]