# how to write a formula to change multiple alphabets in the same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I write function for replace multiple alphabets in one cell, I want to change "space" to "%20", " ' " to "%27", "+" to "%2B"

an example as in the image below

[image: example]

Comment: One option would be some nested `SUBSTITUTE`s.

Comment: Edit : Find : Replace comes to mind as well.

Comment: @BigBen yes I have tried using substitute, but I don't know how to write 3 substitution functions in one cell.

Comment: You nest them `SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE()))`

Comment: @SolarMike Previously I also used find and replace, but I'm tired because I have a lot of files. so if possible how can i find and replace in a different excel file

Comment: Then consider a vba code to loop through the files doing the find : replace.

Comment: @Nata_The_Coco refer this link, as Scott Sir was mentioning about `REDUCE()` & `LAMBDA()` if you are on O365 then only [Complex_Substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70959273/complex-substitute-beyond-64-nesting-limit)

Comment: However as @BigBen Sir mentioned to nest `SUBSTITUTE()` is the easiest way to do,

Comment: @SolarMike one was confirming with Scott Sir, but sir deleted the comment so by that time now removed

Comment: Here is a possible dup, with vba UDFs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685282/can-you-use-substitute-for-many-values-without-nesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using nested `SUBSTITUTE`s:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","%20"),"'","%27"),"+","%2B")
```

[image]

Comment: Since you put this answer, I dupped this question as now it has just about all approaches covered.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, there are other approaches as well, who knows it can be done with Power Query as well, !

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya it can be done with powershell too, but those are outside the scope of this question as it asked for formula answers.  The dup and this answer cover the formula tag.  There may still be answers that use formula, feel free to add answers to the dup.

Comment: Sir, why can't I use that function, when I write it, it doesn't produce results but only writes
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A$1," ","%20"),"'","%27"),"+","%2B")
what's wrong with my excel, why it works for you it doesn't work for me

Comment: @Nata_The_Coco may the cells are formatted as TEXT change it to general

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, may be OP is not aware of Power Query, but PQ is very much part of Excel. But for me i would have followed what BigBen Sir shared or the one JvdV Sir, shared and now since you have shared with VBA its more than enough.