# Recursive LAMBDA to replace characters by specific substitutes from a lookup table

Tags: excel, lambda, excel-formula, excel-lambda

The goal is to iterate through rows of the character table and replace each character with it's substitute.

The character table in this example is `={"&","&amp;";"<","&lt;";">","&gt;";"'","&apos;";"""","&quot;"}`, or:
[image]
*(*Sidenote: `"&","&amp;"` must be last on the list in this exact case, or it will replace other occurrences from previous substitutions, since we're going last to first.)*

Formula:

```
=LAMBDA(XML,Pos,
LET(
Cls,{"&","&amp;";"<","&lt;";">","&gt;";"'","&apos;";"""","&quot;"},
Row,IF(ISOMITTED(Pos),ROWS(Cls),Pos),
Crf,INDEX(Cls,Row,1),
Crr,INDEX(Cls,Row,2),
Sub,SUBSTITUTE(XML,Crf,Crr),
IF(Row=0,XML,ENCODEXML(Sub,Row-1))
))
```

Expected result for `=ENCODEXML("sl < dk & jf")` would be `sl &lt; dk &amp jf`
I'm getting `#VALUE!` error instead.

Comment: see the bottom part of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685282/can-you-use-substitute-for-many-values-without-nesting This will do what you want using scan and Lambda.

Comment: @ScottCraner you're absolutely right, I must admit I could use UDFs too, but I was hoping to learn why my formula doesn't work.
I don't suppose you'd know what the issue is?
It doesn't seem to like the way I handle `Pos` & `Row`, as when I make `Pos` a required argument and manually enter the number of iterations (5 in this case), it works just fine.

Comment: At the bottom of my answer is a formula only version.  I answered that before Lambda and Scan were readily available.  I have not been able to make the name manager versions of Lamba work consistently and since scan and reduce were introduced I do not bother anymore trying.

Comment: @Filcuk try this: `=ENCODEXML("sl < dk & jf",)`

Comment: @ScottCraner blast it, that's it! You're a legend Scott.

Comment: Instead try: `=LET(X,{"&","&amp;";"<","&lt;";">","&gt;";"'","&apos;";"""","&quot;"},REDUCE("sl < dk & jf",INDEX(X,0,1),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,VLOOKUP(b,X,2,0)))))` and safe yourself the hassle of using the name manager.

Comment: @JvdV, will you go to your answer on the linked question and add the version using Reduce?  That way we can have a cannon question to point people to.  This comes up quite often.

Comment: @ScottCraner, due to the nature of that question it does not seem to be fitting to talk about a nested `VLOOKUP()` or using `LET()`. I edited the answer though.

Comment: @JvdV, I would agree, I kind of went overboard on the replace part, giving options to replace with other things beside all the same.  I read my answer and not the question and figured that your formula would be a good fit, again assuming that the user wants to replace each with something different and not the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You need to have an exit on the recursive:

```
=LAMBDA(XML,Pos,
LET(
Cls,{"&","&amp;";"<","&lt;";">","&gt;";"'","&apos;";"""","&quot;"},
Row,IF(ISOMITTED(Pos),ROWS(Cls),Pos),
Crf,INDEX(Cls,Row,1),
Crr,INDEX(Cls,Row,2),
Sub,SUBSTITUTE(XML,Crf,Crr),
IF(Row>1,ENCODEXML(Sub,Row-1),Sub)
))
```

2. You need to add the `,` in the call:

```
=ENCODEXML("sl < dk & jf",)
```

[image]

Or as @Filcuk discovered(and I learned just now) if it is optional it needs to be declared using `[]`

ie:

```
=LAMBDA(XML,[Pos],
LET(
Cls,{"&","&amp;";"<","&lt;";">","&gt;";"'","&apos;";"""","&quot;"},
Row,IF(ISOMITTED(Pos),ROWS(Cls),Pos),
Crf,INDEX(Cls,Row,1),
Crr,INDEX(Cls,Row,2),
Sub,SUBSTITUTE(XML,Crf,Crr),
IF(Row>1,ENCODEXML(Sub,Row-1),Sub)
))
```

Then the `,` is not needed:

```
=ENCODEXML("sl < dk & jf")
```

[image]

Comment: For anyone else reading this, I wasn't aware that optional parameters must be declared using square brackets, so `=LAMBDA(XML,[Pos])` would work as `=ENCODEXML("your text")` without having to add the comma

Answer (score 6):

Just to complement the answer above by Scott; using a recursive lambda through the name manager seems to be obsolete (if one doesn't explicitly need a named function for later use). Since `REDUCE()` is a recursive function on it's own. Therefor, one can apply the following structure:

```
=LET(X,<LookupTable>,REDUCE(<InputValue>,INDEX(X,0,1),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,VLOOKUP(b,X,<ReturnCol>,0)))))
```

Where:

- `<LookupTable>` - Refers to a matrix where the leftmost column holds the lookup values. This is particularly true for `VLOOKUP()` however, with different structures one can start using **`XLOOKUP()`** (to make the solution more applicable);
- `<InputValue>` - A reference to the input string you need to apply the substitution to;
- `<ReturnCol>` - In addition to the 1st point: when one uses `VLOOKUP()` an index refering to the column with the replacement values need to be given;

---

In the case given by OP this would translate to:

```
=LET(X,{"&","&amp;";"<","&lt;";">","&gt;";"'","&apos;";"""","&quot;"},REDUCE("sl < dk & jf",INDEX(X,0,1),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,VLOOKUP(b,X,2,0)))))
```

Comment: And now we have two Questions that we can start pointing to.